# How can I fill an array by calling a method in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to fill an array, declared in data property, by calling a function in methods property in Vue js. Here is the code:

```
<script>
export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
    this.fillLabel();
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels:[],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Users",
            data: [40,20,12,39,10,40]
          }
        ]
      },

    };
  },
  methods: {
    fillLabel() {
      this.chartData.datasets[0].data.map(function (key,value) {
          this.chartData.labels.push(key);
      })

    }
  }
};
</script>
```

But this gives me following error in console :

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'chartData' of undefined"

So how can I fill the labels array(inside chatData) by 0 to length of data array(inside datasets).

I am looking for your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: User arrow function to point the correct this :`this.chartData.datasets[0].data.map((key,value)=>....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your function inside your map function will loose the `this` context. and so its getting undefined.

to solve this problem use an arrow function inside your map.

> this.chartData.datasets[0].data.map((key,value)=> {
>             this.chartData.labels.push(key);
>         })

this will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Only need to introduce `this` to your `fillLabel` method as below:
I tried this solution nd it fixed the problem

```
fillLabel() {
            let th = this;
            th.chartData.datasets[0].data.map(function (key,value) {
                th.chartData.labels.push(key);
            })
            alert(th.chartData.labels)

        },
```